# Quick Sort won't run C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I need my QuickSort to sort decimal numbers not just whole numbers.Below is my code where the file is read, i think this is the issue. How do i fix this?

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        quickSort q_Sort = new quickSort();

        string[] years = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt");
IEnumerable<int> yearArray = years.Select(item => int.Parse(item));
int[] array = yearArray.ToArray();

        q_Sort.array = array;
        q_Sort.len = q_Sort.array.Length;
        q_Sort.QuickSort();

        for (int j = 0; j < q_Sort.len; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(q_Sort.array[j]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You could use built in _Array.Sort_? is there any reason to write your own sorting ?

Comment: Can you describe (in your question) what sort of errors you're getting, or what the order of numbers is given some sample input? E.g., if you give it 11.5, 12.2, and 13.3, how does it sort them? That would help the community find your problem.

Comment: "Won't run anymore"? It just refuses? Or does it give you an exception or compiler error? If the latter, please post that error.

Comment: 'System.FormatException: input string was not in correct format' This is the error im getting.

Comment: You are pushing `double` value to `int` array.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, `int` stores only integers and `double` or `float` can store both integers and floating point numbers.

If you want your program to be able to read both floating point numbers and integers, you should use `double`, or even `decimal` if you want the numbers to be precise, but I don't think there is a need for that. I'll use `double`

This is basically what you need to do,

- change the array to an array of doubles
- change the variables of the `sort` method to be of type double
- use `Convert.ToDouble` instead of `int.Parse`

Try it!

---

If you are too lazy, here's the code:

```
class quickSort
{

    private double[] array = new double[1010];
    private int len;

    public void QuickSort()
    {
        sort(0, len - 1);
    }

    public void sort(double left, double right)
    {
        double pivot;
        double leftend, rightend;

        leftend = left;
        rightend = right;
        pivot = array[left];

        while (left < right)
        {
            while ((array[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
            {
                right--;
            }

            if (left != right)
            {
                array[left] = array[right];
                left++;
            }

            while ((array[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
            {
                left++;
            }

            if (left != right)
            {
                array[right] = array[left];
                right--;
            }
        }

        array[left] = pivot;
        pivot = left;
        left = leftend;
        right = rightend;

        if (left < pivot)
        {
            sort(left, pivot - 1);
        }

        if (right > pivot)
        {
            sort(pivot + 1, right);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        quickSort q_Sort = new quickSort();

        string[] years = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt");
        var yearArray = years.Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item));
        double[] array = yearArray.ToArray();

        q_Sort.array = array;
        q_Sort.len = q_Sort.array.Length;
        q_Sort.QuickSort();

        for (int j = 0; j < q_Sort.len; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(q_Sort.array[j]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I don't actually know the quick sort algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

`int` means integer a whole number no fractions

Comment: change the datatype to 'float' like : private float[] array = new float[1010];

Comment: you need to change all the variables that hold integers too like :  public void sort(float left, float right)
    {
        float pivot, leftend, rightend;

Comment: @Jermaneeeee This is the correct answer, and since you mentioned it is homework I feel it best for you to keep trying.  If you are using Visual Studio to run C# [then debugging will help](http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=visual+studio+debugging&&view=detail&mid=B82F313916C43518B4C7B82F313916C43518B4C7&FORM=VRDGAR) find the exact line the error is happening on.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't run this, so it might not work without some tweaking but when it does work I hope you try and figure out what was wrong with your version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sortQuick
{
    class quickSort
    {

        private double[] array = new double[1010];
        private int len;

        public void QuickSort()
        {
            sort(0, len - 1);
        }

        public void sort(int left, int right)
        {
            int leftend, rightend;
            double pivot;

            leftend = left;
            rightend = right;
            pivot = array[left];

            while (left < right)
            {
                while ((array[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
                {
                    right--;
                }

                if (left != right)
                {
                    array[left] = array[right];
                    left++;
                }

                while ((array[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
                {
                    left++;
                }

                if (left != right)
                {
                    array[right] = array[left];
                    right--;
                }
            }

            left = leftend;
            right = rightend;

            if (left < pivot)
            {
                sort(left, pivot - 1);
            }

            if (right > pivot)
            {
                sort(pivot + 1, right);
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            quickSort q_Sort = new quickSort();

            double[] years = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt");
            IEnumerable<double> yearArray = years.Select(item => double.Parse(item));
            double[] array = yearArray.ToArray();

            q_Sort.array = array;
            q_Sort.len = q_Sort.array.Length;
            q_Sort.QuickSort();

            for (int j = 0; j < q_Sort.len; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q_Sort.array[j]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Ok, your code was hard to modifyso I got the original code from [here](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/QuickSort_Recursive.html) and modified it to work with double. So here is a working version (I tested it).

```
class Program
    {
        static public int Partition(double[] numbers, int left, int right)
        {
            double pivot = numbers[left];
            while (true)
            {
                while (numbers[left] < pivot)
                    left++;

                while (numbers[right] > pivot)
                    right--;

                if (left < right)
                {
                    double temp = numbers[right];
                    numbers[right] = numbers[left];
                    numbers[left] = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    return right;
                }
            }
        }

        static public void QuickSort_Recursive(double[] arr, int left, int right)
        {
            // For Recusrion
            if (left < right)
            {
                int pivot = Partition(arr, left, right);

                if (pivot > 1)
                    QuickSort_Recursive(arr, left, pivot - 1);

                if (pivot + 1 < right)
                    QuickSort_Recursive(arr, pivot + 1, right);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] numbers = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt").Select(p => double.Parse(p)).ToArray();
            int len = 9;

            Console.WriteLine("QuickSort By Recursive Method");
            QuickSort_Recursive(numbers, 0, len - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: I did try it with a text file and it is working fine, just replaced that line: double[] numbers = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt").Select(p => double.Parse(p)).ToArray();