# How to make Quick Sort sort decimal numbers C#

Tags: c#, sorting

Here is a Quick Sort program that reads the numbers from the file and then sorts them smallest to highest. I need it to be able to do the exact same but for numbers with decimals. I understand there is ways of converting int to double, decimal or float, but I've tried everything i can and nothing is working, can someone show me how they would change this code in order to make it work. Below is how i've attempted to do it:

```
class quickSort
{

private double[] array = new double[1010];
private int len;

public void QuickSort()
{
    sort(0, len - 1);
}

public void sort(double left, double right)
{
    double pivot;
    double leftend, rightend;

    leftend = left;
    rightend = right;
    pivot = array[left];

    while (left < right)
    {
        while ((array[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
        {
            right--;
        }

        if (left != right)
        {
            array[left] = array[right];
            left++;
        }

        while ((array[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
        {
            left++;
        }

        if (left != right)
        {
            array[right] = array[left];
            right--;
        }
    }

    array[left] = pivot;
    pivot = left;
    left = leftend;
    right = rightend;

    if (left < pivot)
    {
        sort(left, pivot - 1);
    }

    if (right > pivot)
    {
        sort(pivot + 1, right);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    quickSort q_Sort = new quickSort();

    string[] years = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt");
    var yearArray = years.Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item));
    double[] array = yearArray.ToArray();

    q_Sort.array = array;
    q_Sort.len = q_Sort.array.Length;
    q_Sort.QuickSort();

    for (int j = 0; j < q_Sort.len; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(q_Sort.array[j]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
  }
}
```

Comment: well, you can start by changing most of the `int`s to `double`.

Comment: How are you converting the numbers to have decimal? In your example you are parse by an int into an IEnumerable of of ints... you should try doubles

Comment: show us the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: You can't even do that with a copy-paste ready code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733106/quick-sort-wont-run-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your end goal is to purely sort the array, you could just use Linq!

```
string[] years = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt");
            var yearArray = years.Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item));
            double[] array = yearArray.ToArray();

            var sorted = array.OrderBy(a => a);
```

However, if you wish to amend your QuickSort class, you could do it like this with minimal changes to your original code. It is only the array that needs to support doubles. Your supporting variables used to manage indexing can stay as integers:

```
class quickSort
    {
        private double[] array = new double[1010];

        private int len;

        public void QuickSort()
        {
            sort(0, len - 1);
        }

        public void sort(int left, int right)
        {
            double pivot;
            int leftend, rightend;

            leftend = (int)left;
            rightend = (int)right;
            pivot = array[left];

            while (left < right)
            {
                while ((array[right] >= pivot) && (left < right))
                {
                    right--;
                }

                if (left != right)
                {
                    array[left] = array[right];
                    left++;
                }

                while ((array[left] <= pivot) && (left < right))
                {
                    left++;
                }

                if (left != right)
                {
                    array[right] = array[left];
                    right--;
                }
            }

            array[left] = pivot;
            pivot = left;
            left = leftend;
            right = rightend;

            if (left < pivot)
            {
                sort(left, Convert.ToInt32(pivot - 1));
            }

            if (right > pivot)
            {
                sort(Convert.ToInt32(pivot + 1), right);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            quickSort q_Sort = new quickSort();

            string[] years = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\WS1_Rain.txt");
            var yearArray = years.Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item));
            double[] array = yearArray.ToArray();

            var sorted = array.OrderBy(a => a);

            q_Sort.array = array;
            q_Sort.len = q_Sort.array.Length;
            q_Sort.QuickSort();

            for (int j = 0; j < q_Sort.len; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q_Sort.array[j]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me a lot so easily!

Comment: I assume you mean the full sorting functionality? Regarding my initial quick answer, you can do var sorted = array.OrderByDescending(a => a);

Comment: Use LINQ ! Don't be hard core! `var sorted = array.OrderByDescending(a => a);`

Comment: @Stamos tbh this seems like a homework assignment. Using LINQ would be a shortcut and the student wouldn't learn anything about data manipulation, arrays, types, etc. They also wouldn't learn how to design a medium-complexity (for the level of experience) program.